# Getting User input to show up in LazyList using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose, material-design, android-jetpack

I'm having trouble getting my User input to show up in my LazyList. I'm getting the User's input through the ModelBottomSheet. However, when I try and save the user input, it doesn't show up in my LazyList.
I'm thinking it's perhaps to do with my User class and testUser set up. I'm a student working on this with another person. They set up our User class and testUser, but I'm not sure if maybe it's not completely in a Compose friendly way? I've been having a bit of trouble figuring out State management. Any input is greatly appreciated <3!

**User class:**

```
class User (
    var name: String,
    val email: String
    )
{
    val currentTasks : MutableList<Task> = ArrayList()
    val archivedTasks: MutableList<Task> = ArrayList()
    private var currentPoints: Int = 0
    private var lifetimePoints: Int = 0
    private var nextTaskID: Int = 0
    var categories: MutableList<Category> = ArrayList()


    fun startUp(){
        addCategory(Category("Default"))
        addCategory(Category("Chores"))
        addCategory(Category("Home"))
        addCategory(Category("Work"))
        addTask(Task("Task 1", categories[0], "High", "Hard", false))
        addTask(Task("Task 2", categories[1], "Medium", "Medium", false))
        addTask(Task("Task 3", categories[2], "Low", "Hard", false))
        addTask(Task("Task 4", categories[0], "Medium", "Easy", false))
    }


    fun getLifetimePoints(): Int {
        return lifetimePoints
    }

    fun getCurrentPoints(): Int {
        return currentPoints
    }

    fun numCurrentTasks(): Int {
        return currentTasks.size
    }

    fun numTotalTasks(): Int {
        return currentTasks.size + archivedTasks.size
    }

    fun getNextTaskID(): Int {
        return nextTaskID
    }
    fun addTask(task: Task){
        currentTasks.add(task)
        //to do: categories solution

    }

    fun archiveTask(task: Task){
        currentTasks.remove(task)
        archivedTasks.add(task)
    }


    fun deleteTask(task: Task){
        currentTasks.remove(task)
    }

    private fun minusCurrPoints(points: Int){
        currentPoints -= points
    }
    fun minusPoints(points: Int){
        currentPoints -= points
        lifetimePoints -= points
    }

    fun addPoints(points: Int){
        currentPoints += points
        lifetimePoints += points
    }


    fun redeemPrize(prize: Prize){
        minusCurrPoints(prize.cost)
    }

    fun addCategory(cat: Category){
        if (categories.contains(cat)){
           return
        }
        val newMap = HashMap<String, Task>()
        categories.add(cat)
    }

    private fun removeCategory(cat: Category){
        if (!categories.contains(cat)){
            return
        }
        categories.remove(cat)
    }
}
```

**MainScreen w/ TestUser**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun TaskScreen(contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()) {

    val testUser = User("jason", "jason@hotmail.com")
    testUser.startUp()
    var categories = testUser.categories
    var tasks = testUser.currentTasks



    // State to track if the category dropdown menu is open
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var showTaskBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }



    // State to track if what categories are Switched on or off
    val categoryCheckedState = remember {
        mutableStateMapOf<Category, Boolean>().apply {
            categories.forEach { category ->
                this[category] = true
            }
        }
    }

    // State to track the Checkboxes checked state for tasks
    val checkboxCheckedState = remember {
        mutableStateMapOf<Task, Boolean>().apply {
            tasks.forEach { task ->
                this[task] = task.checked
            }
        }
    }

    // State to track the selected categories
    var selectedCategories by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<Category>()) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(contentPadding)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
        ) {
            // Category Button with dropdown menu
            Box {
                ElevatedButton(onClick = { expanded = true }) {
                    Text("Category")
                }
                CustomDropdownMenu(
                    expanded = expanded,
                    onExpandedChange = { expanded = it },
                    categories = categories,
                    categoryCheckedState = categoryCheckedState,
                    onCategoryClick = { category ->
                        val isChecked = categoryCheckedState[category] ?: false
                        categoryCheckedState[category] = !isChecked
                        selectedCategories = if (isChecked) {
                            selectedCategories - category
                        } else {
                            selectedCategories + category
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
            // Priority Button - Needs to be implemented to sort Priority ratings
            ElevatedButton(
                onClick = { /* Handle button click */ }
            ) {
                Text("Priority")
            }
            // Difficulty Button - Needs to be implemented to sort Difficulty ratings
            ElevatedButton(onClick = { /* Handle button click */ }) {
                Text("Difficulty")
            }
        }
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            LazyColumn(
                //modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp)
            ) {
                val groupedTasks = tasks.groupBy { it.category }
                // Shows categories on screen that haven't been switched off
                categories.forEach { category ->
                    if (categoryCheckedState[category] == true) {
                        // Sticky header for each category
                        stickyHeader {
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .background(
                                        Color.LightGray.copy(alpha = 0.4f),
                                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                                    )
                                    .padding(5.dp)
                            ) {
                                Text(
                                    text = category.name,
                                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        // List of tasks under each category
                        items(groupedTasks[category] ?: emptyList()) { task ->
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .padding(vertical = 3.dp)
                                    .border(
                                        1.dp,
                                        Color.Gray.copy(alpha = 0.4f),
                                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                                    )
                            ) {
                                Row(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .padding(vertical = 8.dp),
                                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                                ) {
                                    // Color coded based on difficulty Checkbox for task
                                    Checkbox(
                                        checked = checkboxCheckedState[task] ?: false,
                                        onCheckedChange = { isChecked ->
                                            checkboxCheckedState[task] = isChecked
                                            task.checked = isChecked
                                        },
                                        colors = CheckboxDefaults.colors(
                                            uncheckedColor = getDifficultyColor(task.difficulty),
                                            checkedColor = getDifficultyColor(task.difficulty)
                                        )
                                    )
                                    // Task name
                                    Text(
                                        text = task.name,
                                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 1.dp)
                                    )
                                    // Priority icons - Will find another approach to show priority that clutters screen less
//                                repeat(getPriorityIconCount(task.priority)) {
//                                    Icon(
//                                        imageVector = Icons.Outlined.PriorityHigh,
//                                        contentDescription = "Priority High",
//                                        modifier = Modifier
//                                            .padding(start = 0.dp, end = 0.dp)
//                                    )
//                                }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // Custom floating action button for adding tasks
            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomEnd,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                TaskFloatingActionButton(
                    onClick = { showTaskBottomSheet = true }
                )
            }
        }

        if (showTaskBottomSheet) {
            TaskBottomSheet(
                padding = contentPadding,
                showTaskBottomSheet = showTaskBottomSheet,
                categories = categories,
                onClose = { showTaskBottomSheet = false },
                onTaskSave = { newTask ->
                    testUser.addTask(newTask)
                    showTaskBottomSheet = false
                    Log.d("NewTask", "Name: ${newTask.name}, Category: ${newTask.category}, Priority: ${newTask.priority}, Difficulty: ${newTask.difficulty}")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Bottom Sheet**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TaskBottomSheet(
    padding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(),
    showTaskBottomSheet: Boolean,
    categories: List<Category>,
    onClose: () -> Unit,
    onTaskSave: (Task) -> Unit
) {
    var isDifficultyMenuExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var isPriorityMenuExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var isCategoryMenuExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val difficultyOptions = listOf("Low", "Medium", "High")
    var selectedDifficulty by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val priorityOptions = listOf("Low", "Medium", "High")
    var selectedPriority by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var selectedCategory by remember { mutableStateOf(Category("")) }
    var taskName by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    if (showTaskBottomSheet) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = onClose,
            sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(padding)
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(15.dp)
                    //.fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    // User input field
                    TextField(
                        value = taskName,
                        onValueChange = { taskName = it },
                        label = { Text("Input new task here") }
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))

                    // Category button
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth(),
                        //  .padding(16.dp),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
                    ) {
                        Column {

                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .offset(y = (-10).dp)
                                    .padding(bottom = 40.dp)
                            ) {
                                ElevatedButton(onClick = { isCategoryMenuExpanded = true }) {
                                    Text(selectedCategory.name.ifBlank { "Category" })
                                }
                            }

                            DropdownMenu(
                                expanded = isCategoryMenuExpanded,
                                onDismissRequest = { isCategoryMenuExpanded = false },
                                modifier = Modifier.requiredSizeIn(maxHeight = 160.dp)
                            ) {
                                categories.forEach { category ->
                                    DropdownMenuItem(
                                        text = { Text(category.name) },
                                        onClick = {
                                            selectedCategory = category
                                            isCategoryMenuExpanded = false
                                        }
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        // Difficulty button
                        Column {
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .offset(y = (-10).dp)
                                    .padding(bottom = 40.dp)
                            ) {
                                ElevatedButton(onClick = { isDifficultyMenuExpanded = true }) {
                                    Text(selectedDifficulty.ifBlank { "Difficulty" })
                                }
                            }
                            DropdownMenu(
                                expanded = isDifficultyMenuExpanded,
                                onDismissRequest = { isDifficultyMenuExpanded = false }
                            ) {
                                difficultyOptions.forEach { option ->
                                    DropdownMenuItem(
                                        text = { Text(option) },
                                        onClick = {
                                            selectedDifficulty = option
                                            isDifficultyMenuExpanded = false
                                        }
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        // Priority button
                        Column {
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .offset(y = (-10).dp)
                                    .padding(bottom = 40.dp)
                            ) {
                                ElevatedButton(onClick = { isPriorityMenuExpanded = true }) {
                                    Text(selectedPriority.ifBlank { "Priority" })
                                }
                            }
                            DropdownMenu(
                                expanded = isPriorityMenuExpanded,
                                onDismissRequest = { isPriorityMenuExpanded = false }
                            ) {
                                priorityOptions.forEach { option ->
                                    DropdownMenuItem(
                                        text = { Text(option) },
                                        onClick = {
                                            selectedPriority = option
                                            isPriorityMenuExpanded = false
                                        }
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp))
                    // Icon in lower right corner
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
                    ) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(40.dp)
                                .clickable {
                                    val newTask = Task(
                                        name = taskName,
                                        category = selectedCategory,
                                        priority = selectedPriority,
                                        difficulty = selectedDifficulty,
                                        checked = false
                                    )
                                    onTaskSave(newTask)
                                    onClose()
                                }
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Filled.SaveAs,
                                contentDescription = "Input Button to save new task",
                                modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding new tasks to `taskList` does not cause `recomposition` as it does not update any `state` and compose runtime does not get notified, make `testUser` as a `state` instead and update the `state` while adding new task

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun TaskScreen(contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()) {
    val testUser = mutableStateOf(User("jason", "jason@hotmail.com").also{ it.startUp() })
    var categories = testUser.value.categories
    var tasks = testUser.value.currentTasks
   // rest of code ...
```

And in `TaskBottomSheet`

```
if (showTaskBottomSheet) {
       TaskBottomSheet(
           padding = contentPadding,
           showTaskBottomSheet = showTaskBottomSheet,
           categories = categories,
           onClose = { showTaskBottomSheet = false },
           onTaskSave = { newTask ->
               testUser.value = testUser.value.apply {
                   addTask(newTask(
               }
               showTaskBottomSheet = false
               Log.d("NewTask", "Name: ${newTask.name}, Category: ${newTask.category}, Priority: ${newTask.priority}, Difficulty: ${newTask.difficulty}")
           }
        )
}
```